# Brill-Noether statement for plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, brill-noether

Let $C$ be a smooth degree $d$ curve in the plane. If $d$ is large (at least 5 or so), then $C$ is not Brill-Noether general because it admits a $g^2_d$. What, then, is the correct statement of Brill-Noether theory for $C$? i.e.,

> For a fixed integer $n>0$, what is
>   $$\max \{h^0(C,D) : D \in Pic^n(C)\}?$$

Here's a guess that I cannot prove correct. By Riemann-Roch and adjunction, we have
$$ h^0(C,D) = 1+n-g + h^0(C,(d-3)H-D),$$
where $H$ is the class of a line restricted to $C$. Again by adjunction, $h^0(C,(d-3)H-D)$ equals the dimension of the space of degree $d-3$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ containing the divisor $D$ (thought of as a subscheme of the plane).

Maximizing this number is therefore equivalent to arranging the points of $D$ so that they impose as few conditions as possible on $(d-3)$-forms. The natural way to do this is to put them on lines. That is, we take $\lfloor n/d\rfloor$ lines containing $d$ points of $C$ each, plus some remainder $r<d$ points, perhaps also on a line. The $(d-3)$-forms that contain these points must contain each line, and therefore there are either
$$\binom{d-1-\lfloor n/d\rfloor}{2}-r \qquad \text{or} \qquad \binom{d-2-\lfloor n/d\rfloor}{2}$$
$(d-3)$-forms containing our divisor $D$. Is this optimal? How can it be proved?